# Change color of the clicked paper-button

Tags: html, css, button

How can I change color of the paper-button when button is clicked?

So far I have made this

```
   <style>
    .period-button {
      width: 100px;
    }

    .period-button.active {
      background-color: red;
    }

  </style>

  <div class="card-content">
    <div class="command">
      <div align="center" style="margin:1rem;">
        <paper-button class="button period-button" toggles on-click="ReportByDay">@Html.Resource("Default_Day")</paper-button>
        <paper-button class="button period-button" toggles on-click="ReportByWeek">@Html.Resource("Default_Week")</paper-button>
        <paper-button class="button period-button" toggles on-click="ReportByMonth">@Html.Resource("Default_Month")</paper-button>
      </div>
    </div>
```

....

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
  $(".period-button").on("click", function () {
    $(this).addClass("active").siblings(".period-button").removeClass("active")
  })
</script>
```

But this is not working for me.
Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to add `tabindex` attribute and try to use `:focus` instead of `active` if you want to add `background-color` after clicked

***Stack Snippet***

```css
.period-button {
  width: 100px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 0 10px;
}

.period-button:focus {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<paper-button tabindex="0" class="button period-button" toggles on-click="ReportByDay">Default_Day</paper-button>
```

***Updated***: If you want to change `background` on click and does not want to remove that color on outside click, better to use `jQuery` to add `active` class

***Stack Snippet***

```css
.period-button {
  width: 100px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 0 10px;
}

.period-button.active {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<paper-button tabindex="0" class="button period-button" toggles on-click="ReportByDay">Default_Day</paper-button>
<paper-button tabindex="0" class="button period-button" toggles on-click="ReportByDay">Default_Day</paper-button>
<paper-button tabindex="0" class="button period-button" toggles on-click="ReportByDay">Default_Day</paper-button>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(".period-button").on("click", function() {
    $(this).addClass("active").siblings(".period-button").removeClass("active")
  })
</script>
```

Comment: There is a problem with this solution. If you click button it changes color but it doesn't stay red if you click outside of the button. So if i have more than one button and i want to see selected button this won't work for me

Comment: @user2171512 this feature is not mentioned in your question...So better to edit your question...for this you will need jQuery....updated the answer....

Comment: I did like you have here, but nothing happens. When i debug i cannot get in jQuery part

Comment: @user2171512 you will have to include the `jQuery` library first and then write the jQuery code below that library using script tag

Comment: See what i have done and so far i don't see any progress. Still doesn't work. Am i doing some mistake ?

Comment: @user2171512 there is a problem in using `script` tag in your code...check my updated second solution